# Laravel datatable fixed columns

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

How can i set fixed right column(action) in laravel datatables like  [this simple example](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html)  - not work in laravel). Thanks

```
tableWatches = $('.datatable-watches').DataTable({
        orderCellsTop: true,
        fixedHeader: false,
        dom: "Bfrtip",
        "pageLength": 50,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        scrollY:        true,
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,

    paging:false,
    fixedColumns:   {
        leftColumns: 1,
        rightColumns: 1
    },
        "ajax": {
            url: "/admin/watches/all-watches",
            data: {
                condition: condition,
            }
        },
        "searchCols": [
       .................
        ],
        columns: [
       ..................
        ],

    });
```

Method, which created table content

And this part (

```
fixedColumns:   {
            leftColumns: 1,
            rightColumns: 1
    },
```

not worked, without errors and warnings, columns still arent fixed.

Answer (score 0):

### Need more explanation!

Totally there is no difference between plain js datatable and yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle.
If you wanna use it locally, just need a 100% with table:

```
<table id="users" class="table responsive" width="100%"></table>
```

And a js script to feed datatable by jso data:

```
$('#users').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    "data": [
     {
         "first_name": "the first name1",
         "last_name": "the last name1"
     },
     {
         "first_name": "the first name2",
         "last_name": "the last name2"
     },
    ]
    "columns": [
     { 
         data: "first_name", title: 'first_name',
         width: '10%', // You can define each column width in the table
         sortable: true,
         searchable: false
     },
     { 
         data: "last_name", title: 'last_name',
         width: '10%',
         sortable: true,
         searchable: false
     }
    ]
});
```

Also for server side feeding datatables, Just use ajax:

```
$('#users').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        "columns": [
         { 
             data: "first_name", title: 'first_name',
             width: '10%', // You can define each column width in the table
             sortable: true,
             searchable: false
         },
         { 
             data: "last_name", title: 'last_name',
             width: '10%',
             sortable: true,
             searchable: false
         }
        ]
        ajax: {
            url: your_post_url_returning_datatable_object_json,
            type: 'POST'
        },
    });
```

As i mentioned, you can define each column of table or make horizontally scrollable:

```
scrollX: '100%',
```